# Django - Trigger signals on object create and saved in different models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-signals

So I had this custom user model on my project.

I want the user can register as a `Profile` and `Client`. I created two different models extended from my custom `User` model.

The problem is, every time I sign-up from the `client` form, it also saved to the `Profile` model, And the opposite.

Let say on my `accounts` app:

```py
# model.py

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    email = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=14)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Influencer Profile'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then inside my `client` app:

```py
# model.py
from accounts.models import User


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Client Profile'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username} Client Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And my `signals.py` looks like:

`accounts/signals.py`

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

And one more `signals` on my `clients` app:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_client_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Client.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Client) #using User as a sender but didn't work.
def save_client_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.client.save()
```

How can I save this user registration to these `models` without affecting each other? I also use two different registration forms for each app. If the user registers from the `client` form, then it should be saved in the `client` model, not saved in both models (`accounts` and `clients`), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

That's how the signals work in Django. When `User` model is created, all registered receivers will be called, regardless of which form is used to create `User`.

Can you create `Profile` object in profile creation form and `Client` object in client creation form instead of using signals?